# ReactJS complex hierarchy and component form submission

Tags: reactjs

I have a large form that has 4 sections within it.

It look like this:

```
  _______________
  |      |      |
  |  1   |  2   |
  |______|______|
  |      |      |
  |  3   |  4   |
  |______|______|
```

All sections form their own jsx file. Section 1 is called Section1.jsx, Section 2 is called Section2.jsx and so on.

Section 1 basically is contact information, you fill up your name, company, address etc. It's pretty simple.

Section 2 is basically the same as section 1, but it's a list of options you can pick from. What you change in section 2, changes some kind of form control in section 4. Like if I have a dropdown that says "use metric instead of english converstion" then section 4 will have different units.

Section 3 is simple, section 4 is a grid.

Now, I have all my components up and running, but now I'm having trouble finding a way to look at all the states of my react components, and bubble up the data to the parents, before I do a form submission.

So here's a heirarchy of what I'm talking about:

- ReactJS Root node

  - ReactJS Section1 node

    - Renders: 5 html input boxes
  - ReactJS Section2 node

    - ReactJS dropdown1 node

      - Renders: select drop down (uses select2.js on componentDidMount)
    - ReactJS dropdown2 node

      - Renders: select drop down (uses select2.js on componentDidMount)
    - ReactJS dropdown3 node

      - Renders: select drop down (uses select2.js on componentDidMount)
    - ReactJS dropdown4 node

      - Renders: select drop down (uses select2.js on componentDidMount)
  - ReactJS Section3 node

    - ReactJS dropdown1 node

      - Renders: select drop down (uses select2.js on componentDidMount)
  - ReactJS Section4 node

    - Renders: table and creates rows that is used in localstorage (uses datatables.js on componentDidMount)

And I have a submit button. I need to go through all of these sections, found in different files, to submit all collected data on this form, and I'm having a tough time finding the best way to do this.

ReactJS seems to shine when it comes to Parent to Child, or Child to Parent relationships. But it becomes harder with Parent to Child to Grandchild, or Grandchild to Child to Parent to GrandParent. This seems like crazy maintenance, especially if I want to add newer nested components within one of these sections. Isn't there a way where I can have some kind of mechanism attached to each of these react nodes, that registers these state of the data, and allows the submit button to be aware of this mechanism and just submit it whenever?

Should I be looking into Flux for this? I kinda started to, but I find myself thinking that adding this to my project is making things more complicated than it needs to be, and I find myself going further down the rabbit hole.

Or do I need to add something like AngularJS and attach listeners to all my fields? I've seen projects where AngularJS and ReactJS is used together, and reactjs is only used for the rendering.

I happened to read this article a bit:
http://ctheu.com/2015/02/12/how-to-communicate-between-react-components/

Explains the 3 relationships:

1. owner to ownee (parent to child)
2. ownee to owner (child to parent)
3. they are not related

For the 3rd option (which is what I really want to know more about) he mentioned using a 3rd party library called PubSub (publish/subscribe) and there's a javascript library found here:

https://github.com/mroderick/PubSubJS

But I'm really not sure if this is the best way to go about it.

Comment: Flux would probably be good so that you don't have to manage all the state in the top level component.

Comment: I've been reading up on Flux a bit more, it just seems too much for me to get into. It heavily relies on Nodejs as a requirement for all their tutorials, so this leads me to believe it's highly coupled with the kind of web server you use. ReactJS is a non-interfering library, and Flux seems like it'd definitely interfere with what I have.

Comment: Flux is just a way you architecture your React code, it's absolutely not coupled with the server at all. I think you should using Flux, in your specific case you will have a `FormStore` keeping the sate of all your sections and a top controller passing sections data as props. When you hit the "submit" button, you have nothing to do since the current state of your form (ie, the result of user inputs) is already maintained in your `FormStore`.

Comment: As others have mentioned, I also highly recommend getting into Flux. By the end of it, you will be easily able to manage application state in one place.

Comment: For example, change event of dropdown triggers an `Action`, which calls `Dispatcher`, which then is heard in `Store` which is where you would save the state. Your main application JS file is hooked to `Store` so whenever something changes in `Store`, it can get the required data from `Store` and pass down to the child (and grand-children) components using `props` i.e. data flowing in one direction. I found **[this article](http://blog.mgechev.com/2015/05/15/flux-in-depth-overview-components/)** to be a really good starting point for Flux.

Comment: what confuses me with flux is the "require" and "export" at the top of all their files.. this is a nodejs thing, I could not find a single tutorial that didn't have this at the top of all of their files. Secondly, a lot of their tutorials uses javascript es6 standards, so that I should grab some html shims to add to my library. Were you able to use flux without using nodejs at all? Also, I already have an mvc architecture that I'm working very well with, I just don't see a point of using flux at this stage just to get react components to play nicely with each other.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I just went ahead and added PubSubJS, as mentioned in the original post. I really do give credit to ctheu for showing this kind of solution in detail, and to mroderick for creating the PubSub library.

https://github.com/mroderick/PubSubJS

This is such an amazing library, I can subscribe all my components to listen to a specific token when they get mounted, and that allows them to "listen" to any kind of changes that gets published.

The great thing about that, is that you can subscribe your components at any time, and whenever something get's published, the components that are subscribed will run their function.

Here's what I mean:

```
// create a function to subscribe to topics
var mySubscriber = function( msg, data ){
    console.log( msg, data );
};

var token = PubSub.subscribe( 'demo', mySubscriber );
```

So far, nothing gets printed to the console:

```
var demoClick = React.createClass({
    getInitialState: function() {
        return {value: 'Hello!'};
    },
    handleChange: function(event) {
        this.setState({value: event.target.value})
        PubSub.publish('demo', event.target.value)
    },
    render: function() {
        var value = this.state.value;
        return (<input type="text" value={value} onChange={this.handleChange} /> );
```

}});

as soon as I change a value in the text box, my console log gets triggered

Now I take the subscription code:

```
var token = PubSub.subscribe( 'demo', mySubscriber );
```

And put it after my react component, it will still trigger when I make changes to the input box.

I can even take this a step further and include this bit of code and add it to the component lifecycle: componentWillMount, and componentWillUnmount.

So in a componentWillMount, I can subscribe, and in a componentWillUnmount, I can unsubscribe the token.

If feels kind of like it's a global event system, but it's really managed by PubSub instead.

Answer (score 0):

You could give your children form components (which all have refs defined in the parent HTML) a val() function so that you can call it from the parent using these refs. All of your data will bubble to the parent but you aren't required to save it in the parent's state.

If you need to pass high-level events to children you can do this easily by passing props to your children components).

Comment: I actually went this route prior, but it just seemed like a very rounabout way of doing things. I really wanted to use a direct function. So in my answer below, I used pubsub, and I created a library called "subscribes", so it has all the subscribes, along with a comment dictating where the publishes are coming from. It worked really well, when I was adding in a new model binding framework. The solution you provided works just as well, but not to my liking.